# How to create a box out of asterisks in java with command line arguments?

Tags: java

I was wanting to create a program in which the user inputs a height and width as a command line argument and the program creates a box made out of asterisks, e.g. java Box  .

```
public class Box {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
         System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println("");
      }
   }
}
```

I have the arguments for the command line so far, but was unsure how to print the asterisks. I have a feeling 2 for loops are needed though.

Comment: Before you can receive help here, post your code above of what you tried, with an explanation of why it didn't work and what behavior you are seeing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is a for loop inside another with some conditions.

First try to print the first (or last) line of the box where you will use the width parameter (use a for loop).

Then print any line of the box, so you will need to use a condition to know if the line is the first or the last. if not, then the program should print an asterisk, followed by spaces, and in the end print another asterisk (use another if-else condition).

Finally, everything you have goes inside a for loop where the line begins at 1 and ends at height value.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, if code is executed with arguments `10 5`, I assume you want output to be:

```
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

You can do this best with a helper method:

```
private static String repeat(char ch, int count) {
    char[] buf = new char[count];
    Arrays.fill(buf, ch);
    return new String(buf);
}
```

Then your code would be something like this:

```
System.out.println(repeat('*', width));
for (int i = 2; i < height; i++)
    System.out.println('*' + repeat(' ', width - 2) + '*');
System.out.println(repeat('*', width));
```

I will leave it to you to adjust this code to handle `width` and/or `height` values of 1.

---

Of course, maybe you meant to print this (which is also a *"box made out of asterisks"*):

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

That's even simpler:

```
char[] buf = new char[width];
Arrays.fill(buf, '*');
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    System.out.println(buf);
```